# Understanding named accessor property attribute

Tags: javascript

At [**8.6.1 sec.**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1) the attributes of named accessor property are given. Let we are creating named accessor property such as

```
var o=Object.create({},{bar:{get: function(){ return 10;}, 
                             set: function(value){ console.log("o.bar is", value)}}})
o.bar=550;
```

It's ok. In console we have `o.bar is 550`. But i have a some doubts. Named accessor property doesn't have `value` attribute. So which attribute is assigned to 550?

How we can return this assigned value? I'm trying to rewrite `get` function such the following:

```
get: function(){ return value;}
```

But I have error:

```
[15:59:41.418] ReferenceError: value is not defined @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:26
```

Please explain me how named accessor property works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Named accesor property doesn't have value attribute. So which attribute is assigned to 550?

None, you have to do that in your setter. It's not done automatically.

> How we can return this assigned value?

From wherever you saved it. For instance, it's fairly common to use a closure for this *(I've put it on multiple lines for clarity)*:

```
var o=Object.create({},(function() {
    var _bar = 10;

    return {
      bar:{
        get: function(){
          return _bar;
        },
        set: function(value){
          _bar = value;
          console.log("bar set to " + _bar);
        }
      }
    };
})());
o.bar=550;
console.log("o.bar = " + o.bar);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/otoqUzU/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/otoqUzU/1/edit)

Condensed version if you're into that sort of thing: :-)

```
var o=Object.create({},(function() {
    var _bar = 10;

    return {bar:{get: function(){ return _bar; },
                 set: function(value){ _bar = value; console.log("bar set to " + _bar); }}};
})());
o.bar=550;
console.log("o.bar = " + o.bar);
```